# magento 1.9 dont want to change order state to complete automatically

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using magento 1.9 . as we know magento mark order state to complete once payment is received and shipment is created. i want to make completed state independent. 
like no matter payment is received and shipment is created i dont want magento to change the state to completed automatically. i just want the state to be as it was before creating shipment.

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the core source, it looks like the native behavior you described comes from the method `_checkState` (essentially called in the `_beforeSave` method of an order) that you can find in `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php`.

So, you should rewrite the model `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` and modify the method `_checkState` : remove for example the part  `$this->_setState(self::STATE_COMPLETE, true, '', $userNotification);`.